# Mayer-Vietoris sequence for etale cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

Loosely speaking, the general rule for invoking a Mayer-Vietoris sequence is to decompose a topological space $X$ into disjoint nonempty **open** subsets $A$ and $B$ and then proceed. In my case, I am considering a smooth projective curve $C$ over a number field $k$, and an open dense subscheme $X$ given by removing a $k$-rational point $t$ from $C$. The canonical map $\mathcal{O}_C \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{C,t}$ induces an etale morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\, \mathcal{O}_{C,t} \rightarrow C$. So I suppose we can rewrite $C$ as the disjoint union of etale covers $X \cup \mathrm{Spec}\, \mathcal{O}_{C,t}$. The "intersection" of these covers is then the spectrum of fraction field $F$ of $\mathcal{O}_{C,t}$.

**Question 1.** What is this fraction field $F$? I know it has an inclusion into the residue field of $t$, which in this case is $k$ since $t$ is $k$-rational. And so $F$ can be any subfield of $k$, but I'm hoping that it is $k$ itself.

Now that we can both the union and "intersection", we invoke Mayer-Vietoris sequence with coefficients in the etale sheaf $\mathbb{G}_m$ to get

$$... \rightarrow H^1(F,\mathbb{G}_m) \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}(C) \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}(X) \oplus H^2(\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{C,t}),\mathbb{G}_m) \rightarrow H^2(F,\mathbb{G}_m)\rightarrow H^3(C,\mathbb{G}_m) \rightarrow ...$$

As you can see, if $F = k$ then we can easily handle the groups $H^i(F,\mathbb{G}_m)$. Otherwise, I'm not sure if we can still use Hilbert 90 and stuff...

**Question 2.** Is it true that we have $H^i(\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{C,t}),\mathbb{G}_m) \cong H^i(k,\mathbb{G}_m)$? I think its got to do with $\mathcal{O}_{C,t}$ being strictly Henselian or something but I'm not exactly sure about that.

Comment: If you really do mean the fraction field of $\mathcal{O}_{C,t}$, that's the field of rational functions $k(C)$. This doesn't include in a nice way in to the residue field at $t$. Your claimed morphism is also not etale because it's not finitely presented, and there isn't really a map $\mathcal{O}_C\to\mathcal{O}_{C,t}$ - perhaps it's late and I'm misreading, but it seems like there's something seriously off here.

Comment: @KReiser I had a feeling that all went too smoothly, that's why I laid it out here hoping for people to point out where I could've misunderstood. Thanks for the pointers, I'll think about how to fix them.

Comment: @KReiser Sorry I've thought hard about it, maybe I'll refer you to Proposition 8.4 in this [note](https://math.unice.fr/~dehon/CohEtale-09/Elencj_Etale/SUTHERLAND%20.pdf), where I've been trying to imitate the work but over a number field $k$. I don't see how $X$ can be written as the given union, why is $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,\bar{x}})$ an open subset of $X$? Here $\bar{x}$ is a geometric point. Also, isn't a $k$-rational point a geometric point? Since it induces $\mathrm{Spec}\,k \rightarrow X$, and we can just precompose it with $\mathrm{Spec}\,\bar{k} \rightarrow \mathrm{Speck} \,k$